# File operations in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline flow defined as:

```
node("linux_label") {
    println("hostname".execute().txt)
    def filename = "${WORKSPACE}/submoduleinfo.txt"
    stage("Submodule info") {
        def submoduleString = sh script: "git -C ${WORKSPACE} submodule status > ${filename}", returnStdout: true
    }
    String fileContents = new File("$filename}").text
    operateOnFile(fileContents)
}
```

At "new File" I will get an error saying no such file exists. after some troublehshooting I see that the hostname printout will output the jenkins master and not the node "linux_label" where the workspace resides.

Is this how Piepeline should work, i.e. all code that is not part of stage/steps/etc are executed on the jenkins master and not on the wanted node?

What would be a good workaround where I do an operation in one stage and want to operate on the file in the node {} domain?

Answer (score 2):

That is how pipeline works.   You can use readFile to read file from a workspace.  Since you are using just a content of the file for your processing, this will work.

From [tutorial](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md):

> readFile step loads a text file from the workspace and returns its
>   content (do not try to use java.io.File methods — these will refer to
>   files on the master where Jenkins is running, not in the current
>   workspace).

In one of our use case, we added some additional functions using [Shared pipeline library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (env['NODE_NAME'].equals("master")) {
    return new hudson.FilePath(path);
} else {
    return new hudson.FilePath(Jenkins.getInstance().getComputer(env['NODE_NAME']).getChannel(), path);
}
```